# Is it possible to make bulk insert via dynamic query (no stored procedure)?

Tags: c#, oracle11g, entity-framework-6.1

My question is simple like the title says.
We are not allowed to create stored procedures.
So I want to make this via dynamic query (non of any custom types creation, etc.).

It should be so simple as:

```
command.CommandText =
                        "INSERT INTO XXX.privileges VALUES (" +
                        ":in_role_type," +
                        ":in_who," +
                        ":in_action_type," +
                        ":in_privilege_type," +
                        ":in_object_type," +
                        ":in_keys)"
```

Where all parameters are scalar values, but **in_keys** is an array of integers.

I've tried [this approach](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html):

And the error is below:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Array'
```

Comment: Why do you have an entity-framework tag in this question, are you using entity framework?

Comment: Yes, I'm using EF 6.1.3.